# Splitting a string by text language

Tags: r, text, nlp

I am working with a corpus of text documents (stored as one character string each) that are predominantly in English, but include some documents in Spanish and some that repeat the same information in both English and Spanish. I used the `cld2` and `cld3` packages (which implement Chrome's language detection functionality in R) to estimate the languages contained in each string in the corpus. My goal is to process all the strings containing text in both English and Spanish such that the English portions are retained and the Spanish portions are removed.

Here is an example of three of the strings I'm working with:

```
mixed.language.strings <- c("Department of Cultural Affairs and Special Events: Today will be the First Annual Mariachi and Folklorico Festival! Local groups begin at 1:00pm and world renowned headliners start at 3:00pm. It will be located in Millennium Park. Invite your friends, family, and neighbors to participate in this FREE event! \nEnjoy the weather on this beautiful Sunday! \n ************** \n Departamento de Asuntos Culturales y Eventos Especiales: Hoy será el Primer Festival Anual de Mariachi y Balet Folklórico! Los grupos locales comienzan a las 1:00 pm y los grupos de renombre mundial empiezan a las 3:00 pm. Será en el Millennium Park. Inviten a su familia, amigo@s, y vecin@s a este evento completamente GRATIS!", 
"Call or walk into our office for information on the Emergency Heating Repair Program which provides eligible low-income, owner-occupied homes grants for a new heating system.\n\nLlame o visite nuestra oficina para más información sobre un programa de la Ciudad ofreciendo dinero hacía la reparación o instalación de sistemas de calefacción. Dueños de casa de ingresos bajos son elegibles.   \n\n 3476 S. Archer Ave. \n (773) 523-8250", 
"Join me and other local elected officials for a workshop on appealing your property taxes. Homes in West & South townships of Cook County are currently eligible to appeal. See flier for more info, or call my office at 773-523-8250.\n\nLos invito a un taller sobre el proceso de apalear sus impuestos de propiedad. Hogares en los West y East “townships” del Condado de Cook son elegibles ahora para apalear sus impuestos. Por favor refiéranse al volante añadido a este mensaje, o llame mi oficina al 773-523-8250, para más información."
)
```

As far as I've been able to determine, `cld2` and `cld3` can estimate the languages contained within a string, but cannot extract portions of the string based on language.

Is there a different package in R that I can use to identify the portions of each string that are in each language, and split the string in two based on that?

Thanks! Sorry if this isn't clear; it's my first time posting.

Comment: In the three example strings, it looks like the language shifts are all newline delimited.  Is this always the case?  Perhaps you could break the strings into substrings on the newlines, and keep only the substrings that appear to be only english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the approach I suggested in my comment, which will work if you expect newlines in between the languages in your strings. (This is the case in all your examples.  If it's not true in general, perhaps you could try splitting on newlines, periods, exclamations, and question marks)

```
library('cld2')

list.of.strings <- strsplit(mixed.language.strings, '\n')
ExtractEnglishSubstrings <- function(string.vector) {
  return(string.vector[which(detect_language(string.vector) == 'en')])
}

lapply(list.of.strings, ExtractEnglishSubstrings)
```

This outputs

```
[[1]]
[1] "Department of Cultural Affairs and Special Events: Today will be the First Annual Mariachi and Folklorico Festival! Local groups begin at 1:00pm and world renowned headliners start at 3:00pm. It will be located in Millennium Park. Invite your friends, family, and neighbors to participate in this FREE event! "
[2] "Enjoy the weather on this beautiful Sunday! "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

[[2]]
[1] "Call or walk into our office for information on the Emergency Heating Repair Program which provides eligible low-income, owner-occupied homes grants for a new heating system."

[[3]]
[1] "Join me and other local elected officials for a workshop on appealing your property taxes. Homes in West & South townships of Cook County are currently eligible to appeal. See flier for more info, or call my office at 773-523-8250."
```

If you prefer the strings stitched back together and returned in a vector instead of as a list of vectors, this modification should do that...

```
ExtractEnglishSubstrings <- function(string.vector) {
  english.vector <- string.vector[which(detect_language(string.vector) == 'en')]
  reassembled.string <- paste0(english.vector, collapse=' ')
  return(reassembled.string)
}

unlist(lapply(list.of.strings, ExtractEnglishSubstrings))
```

returns

```
[1] "Department of Cultural Affairs and Special Events: Today will be the First Annual Mariachi and Folklorico Festival! Local groups begin at 1:00pm and world renowned headliners start at 3:00pm. It will be located in Millennium Park. Invite your friends, family, and neighbors to participate in this FREE event!  Enjoy the weather on this beautiful Sunday! "
[2] "Call or walk into our office for information on the Emergency Heating Repair Program which provides eligible low-income, owner-occupied homes grants for a new heating system."                                                                                                                                                                                    
[3] "Join me and other local elected officials for a workshop on appealing your property taxes. Homes in West & South townships of Cook County are currently eligible to appeal. See flier for more info, or call my office at 773-523-8250."
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is a great solution. I hadn't noticed the prevalence of newlines. A quick check shows that of the 95 mixed language strings in my corpus, 93 of them contain newlines. So I can use this approach for those and then manually fix the last two.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is tackling a similar problem, I made a few modifications to the excellent code that [HardlandMason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4513246/harlandmason) offered.

The code below *keeps substrings*, similar to what HarlandMason offered, with two changes: (1) rather than taking in a vector of character strings as its input, it takes in a single character string and outputs a single character string; and (2) it allows you to input the language of the substrings you would like to keep (in the format required by the `cld2::detect_language` function).

```
KeepSubstrings.bylanguage <- function(string, language) {
string.vector <- unlist(strsplit(string, '\n'))
cut.vector <- string.vector[which(cld2::detect_language(string.vector) == language)]
reassembled.string <- paste0(cut.vector, collapse=' ')
return(reassembled.string)
}
```

The code below is similar but *removes substrings* of a certain language rather than retaining only substrings of a certain language (this is useful if some of the substrings are very short and thus pose problems for the `detect_language` function, and you would rather be more cautious about retaining substrings about which the function is uncertain):

```
RemoveSubstrings.bylanguage <- function(string, language) {
string.vector <- unlist(strsplit(string, '\n'))
cut.vector <- string.vector[which(cld2::detect_language(string.vector) != language)]
reassembled.string <- paste0(cut.vector, collapse=' ')
return(reassembled.string)
}
```

Both of these can be applied over a vector of character strings using `lapply` or `sapply` as suggested in the previous answer.